# z-index does not work

Tags: html, css

I have a question I am trying to use z-index to make the feel of 3D to my design but I can not see any change when I use it

my css is as follow:

```
 .test1
    {
        background-color:#666;
        opacity:0.4;
        width:500px;
        height:500px;
        z-index:1000px; 
        position:absolute;
        top:0;
        left:0;

    }
```

and the fiddle link is :

http://jsfiddle.net/hminaee/a89Z4/

Can anyone tell me what is the problem?

Answer (score 6):

z-index takes a number, not a measurement.

```
z-index : 30;
```

Also, it doesn't magically make anything 3D; all it does is move that box in front of any other box in the same position as it, which has a lower z-index (or is `position:static;`).

If you expected scaling or shearing, then you should do research on `transform : rotate3d`, and its ilk.

Comment: This is the answer @Hamed Minaee

Comment: Thanks,I want to use this div to cover the whole screen and show some progress bar in it and underneath is the body and I dont want to set body as an static or relative but I want this div seems different or a little bit higher so what is your suggestion  ?

Comment: @HamedMinaee the default value for ***every*** element is `position : static;`. You almost never have to type it, unless you're doing something very specific (like adding/removing a class to make a div `fixed`/`static`), and you want `fixed` to be the default...

Answer (score 2):

For one, `z-index` should be a unitless number. (e.g. `z-index : 1000;` not `z-index: 1000px;`)

But also your jsfiddle only contains one element, so I'm not sure what you expect to happen. It seems like maybe you don't understand what `z-index` does. You might want to read:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Understanding_z_index